# Mounting GCE Persistent Disk on my local machine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to mount a GCE persistent disk that was created by a Kubernetes PersistentVolumeClaim resource (on GKE) to my local machine.

I created a PersistentVolumeClaim (that creates a persistent volume in GCE):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: profiler-disk
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

I tried to use [gcsfuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to mount the disk as is written in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets):

> You can use the Google Cloud Storage FUSE tool to mount a Cloud Storage bucket to your Compute Engine instance. The mounted bucket behaves similarly to a [persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#pdspecs) even though Cloud Storage buckets are object storage.

with the command:

```
gcsfuse profiler-disk hello
```

but I am getting:

> daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: setUpBucket: OpenBucket: Unknown bucket "profiler-disk"

I was able to load an actual bucket, so this is not an authorization/authentication issue.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: A Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket and a Google Compute Engine (GCE) Persistent disk are very different things. gcsfuse will only work on GCS.

Comment: @PaulAnnetts thanks for the answer, are you familiar with any other  other way to mount it locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to copy the data using [kubectl cp](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp)

```
kubectl <pod-name>:/path <local-path> -c <container-name>
```